# String formatting in SyncFusion?

Tags: syncfusion

String formatting:

"#0.##%;(#0.##%); "

The above will *format a double into a percentage string with two decimal points, put it into parenthesis if it’s negative and leave it a blank string if it’s zero.*

The problem is, if the double value has no decimal points, eg if the value is 2, then for some reason the resulting string is “2%” and not “2.00%”.

My question is: how do I make it go to “**2.00%**”?

p.s. the formatting is happening on a Syncfusion grid cell object and requires a string mask.

p.s.s. the existing functionality described above in italics must be maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Hashes denote an optional character. Use “#0.00%” (etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string format #0.00% for 2 digital places.

"#" means optional to show the digital while "0" means mandatory to show. In this case (#0.00%) stands for the 2 digital places are mandatory and the digital right before the "." is mandatory as well. If there is any digital before the "0", it will show up. Otherwise, it won't as this digital is optional.

e.g.
2   -> 2.00%

12  -> 12.00%

120 -> 120.00%

11.234 -> 11.23%

And using "P" or "P2" also works fine in this case. "P" stands for percent, "2" is the amount of digital places.
e.g.

```
double number = .2468013;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 24.68 %
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hr-HR")));           
// Displays 24,68%     
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 24.7 %
```

You can refer to the MSDN for [more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).